# How to load list Data to the Dynamic data table returned from the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here is my problem:

In a view called **"Select Event"** user fills some data that are filled into the dynamic data table one by one record. And when he clicks next button, that data is converted to array and passed to the controller. And also it loads the next view(Select Package). In controller that data is stored in session variable.The problem is that I want that data to put again in same dynamic data table when user clicks the back button from another view called **"select package"**. So far I've done this,

returning the stored data in session variable from contoller using json result:

```
public JsonResult PrevDyanamicTable()
{
    List<OrderEvent> eventlist1 = new List<OrderEvent>();

    Order newOrder = new Order();
    if (Session["NewOrder"] != null)
    {
        newOrder = (Order)Session["NewOrder"];
    }
    eventlist1 = newOrder.OrderEvent.ToList();
    OrderEvent[] eventlist = eventlist1.ToArray();
    return Json(eventlist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Get ajax call:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnDynmicTbl", function () {

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/OrderEvents/PrevDyanamicTable/",
    //contentType: "application/json; charset = utf-8",
    success: function (response) {
        debugger;
        window.location.href = "/OrderEvents/Create/"

        var myArray = response;
        $.each(myArray, function (index, OrderEvent) {
            var txtEventId = OrderEvent.EventID;
            var txtEventType = OrderEvent.Venue;
            var txtStartingDate = OrderEvent.StartingDate;
            var txtEndingDate = OrderEvent.EndingDate;
            var txtStartingTime = OrderEvent.StartingTime;
            var txtEndingTime = OrderEvent.EndingTime;
            var txtVenue = OrderEvent.Venue;



            var contactdiv = '<tr class="data-contact-Album">' +
                '<td><input type="text" name="EventID" value="' + txtEventId + '" class="form-control hidden " /></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" name="EventType" value="' + txtEventType + '" disabled="disabled"  class="form-control " /></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" name="StartingDate" value="' + txtStartingDate + '" disabled="disabled"  class="form-control  " /></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" name="EndingDate" value="' + txtEndingDate + '" disabled="disabled"  class="form-control " /></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" name="StartingTime" value="' + txtStartingTime + '" disabled="disabled"  class="form-control " /></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" name="EndingTime" value="' + txtEndingTime + '" disabled="disabled"  class="form-control" /></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" name="Venue" value="' + txtVenue + '" disabled="disabled"  class="form-control " /></td>' +
                '<td><button type="button" id="btnDelete" class="deleteEvent btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">Remove</button><button type="button" id="btnUpdate" class="UpdateEvent btn btn btn-default btn-xs">Update</button></td>' +

                '</tr>; ';

            $('#maintable').append(contactdiv);
        });

    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
  });
});
```

This java script is written on the separate file inside the scripts folder. In here **#btnDynmicTbl** is the back button in **select package** view. **"window.location.href ="/OrderEvent/Create/"** is the view that dynamic data table loads. I have checked for the console errors and there wasn't anything.I'm new to asp.net MVC.I've managed to come this far in project thanks to the help of this stack overflow community.So How to make this work? what are the errors in this code? thanks.

Comment: Your `window.location.href = "/OrderEvents/Create/"` makes no sense - that is making a redirect, so all the code that follows it is pointless (you have already left the page)

Comment: how can I redirect to the particular view?I'm using json result. and already it is returning a value. Is there a way to use same json result to redirct  another action result in another controller? thanks.

Comment: Yes its returning a value, but you ignore it and redirect to another page so its pointless (all that code to create your table rows is executed and added to the current page, but you never see it because you redirect to a new page). Its hard to understand what you trying to do here

Comment: I want to load the same data when he comes back from the next view.there is steps. user fills data and go to next step.when he want to come again the previous step, i want to show the user enterd data before he go to that next view. according to you i understand that i'm doing that in wrong way. any suggestion to load view and execute the code?? thanks

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same view, so to make an ajax call and then do a redirect using `location.href` makes no sense. You can just have a normal link if you want to redirect, but you would need to pass a value back to the method to indicate what you want to generate in the view your navigating to. You have not given enough details in the question to understand what your wanting to generate

Comment: thank you!! I got it, I'll use an action link as back button to load the required view.Thanks again.